# Angular @ViewChild Error 'Cannot read property nativeElement of undefined"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular5

I am new to Angular and facing this issue.

I want to check value for variable `elementRef` if its empty before data shown because I want to display a chart. This is my code:

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('normalDeviasiDaily', {read: ElementRef}) normalDeviasiDaily: ElementRef;
```

**component.html**

```
  <div *ngIf="normalDeviasiDaily">
    <div #normalDeviasiDaily id="normalDeviasiDaily">
      <canvas style="width:100%; height:400px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!normalDeviasiDaily">
    <skeleton-item height="400px"></skeleton-item>
  </div>
```

My issue is `cannot read property nativeElement of undefined`, has anyone else experienced this, please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: did solution solve your problem?

Comment: Can you modify the question so that it will explain the exact behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm using the solution as @TheParam said, after some modification then it works well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are facing this issue because of the `*ngIf` directive won't create a DOM element until the condition becomes `true`.

So instead of using the `*ngIf` use `hidden` property of HTML which will create DOM element but it won't show to the user until condition `false`

```
 <div [hidden]="!normalDeviasiDaily">
    <div #normalDeviasiDaily id="normalDeviasiDaily">
      <canvas style="width:100%; height:400px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="normalDeviasiDaily">
    <skeleton-item height="400px"></skeleton-item>
  </div>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: the result is nothing, no data shown

Comment: toggle the condition of hidden property it will work

Comment: where are you accessing the  normalDeviasiDaily object in your component?

Comment: try to call this in ngAfterViewInit method. for this you need to implement AfterViewInit interface

Comment: uh wait, I've missplace my code, your solution is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is display the skeleton-item if chart is empty.

So what you can do is, hiding the graph when the data is not loaded. Let's say, in your component.ts there is a variable called chartData which stores the chart data. This variable is an asynchronous one, since the chart data gets loaded in to that dynamically.

Try this,

```
  <div [hidden]="chartData">
    <div #normalDeviasiDaily id="normalDeviasiDaily">
      <canvas style="width:100%; height:400px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!chartData">
    <skeleton-item height="400px"></skeleton-item>
  </div>
```

Comment: when I use existing variable there is no skeleton-item showing

Comment: @Lordrauf can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: when I set property to hidden, it will hide my canvas too.

Comment: solved by @TheParam